# How to add text watermark to Excel files using MS Office Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop, watermark

My program should be able to add watermark using interop, not other libraries like Aspose. I managed to add this function for word documents, but I don't know how to do this for Excel. The following code is for word documents.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
                    Application wordApp = new Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShape = null;
                    wordApp.Visible = false;
                    wordApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
                    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(datei.pfad);
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
                    {
                        wordShape = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddTextEffect(
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
                                         datei.TextWasserzeichen, "Arial", (float)60,
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                                         Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                                         150, 150, ref o); 
                        wordShape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                        wordShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                        wordShape.Fill.Solid();
                        wordShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray90;
                        wordShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                        wordShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                        wordShape.Left = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
                        wordShape.Top = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
                    }
                    wordDoc.SaveAs2(datei.newPath + " mit Wasserzeichen in Text.docx", ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
                    wordDoc.Close();
                    wordApp.Quit();
```

My problem is, for example, I could not find something  equivalent to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section or section.Headers Property and so on. It seems to be quite different from word.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape excelShape = null;
                    excelApp.Visible = false;
                    excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
                    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(datei.pfad);
 foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheet in workbook.Sheets)
                    {
                        //add watermark
                    }
```

This is how far I've got. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Excel doesn't really have a watermark feature. You can simulate one by inserting something into the header or footer though.

Comment: Excel Interop uses the same API a VBA macro does. You can record a VBA macro while you add a watermark they way you want and then use the same calls in C#

Comment: The [Add a Watermark in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-watermark-in-excel-a372182a-d733-484e-825c-18ddf3edf009) tutorial explains that Excel doesn't have a watermark feature and shows how to add images, headers and footers to achieve something similar. Watermarks in spreadsheets aren't useful (in fact, they're a hindrance) until you print the spreadsheet, which is why there's no such feature even after 30+ years

Comment: @DavidG Oh, that's sad. Thanks for the information! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sad, not really. A watermark image in an application meant for calculations isn't useful, and actually makes life harder for users. It sounds like you're using the spreadsheet as a report though, something to be printed, exported to PDF or displayed without interaction

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for so much detailed explanation! It seems like I had no idea what it was about, and now Iearned all thanks to you.

Comment: Just consider that this never became a priority in 30-40 years. By now the only real competitor to Excel is Google Sheets and that doesn't have watermarks either.